# 'Dash' object has no attribute 'html'

Tags: python

I am new to Dash, trying to create a page where user can upload three csv files. I am getting an error 'Dash' object has no attribute 'html'. Below is the code I'm trying.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import pandas as pd
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout=app.html.Div([
html.H1('Training Data Set'),
    dcc.Upload(id='upload-training-data', children=html.Div([
    'Drag and Drop or ',
    html.A('Select Files')
])),
html.H1('Meta Data'),
dcc.Upload(id='upload-meta-data', children=html.Div([
    'Drag and Drop or ',
    html.A('Select Files')
])),
html.H1('Validation Data Set'),
dcc.Upload(id='upload-validation-data', children=html.Div([
    'Drag and Drop or ',
    html.A('Select Files')
]))
])
```

I tried installing and uninstalling dash and other components but still not able to resolve

Comment: Should `app.html.Div` be `html.Div`?

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I corrected and its working fine